# Correct Use Of avcodec_encode_video2() Flush

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, video-encoding

I have a camera sending pictures to a callback function and I want to make a movie with this pictures using `FFmpeg`. I have followed the `decoding_encoding` example [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2decoding_encoding_8c-example.html) but am not sure how to use the `got_output` for flushing the encoder and getting the delayed frames.

1. **Shoud I encode all my camera's pictures when they arrive, and later when I want to stop capturing and close the video, I do the flush loop?**

Or

2. **Should I do the flush periodically, let's say, every 100 pictures received?**

My video capture program could be running for hours, so I am worried about how this delayed frames work in memory consumption, if they stack up there until the flush, this could take all my memory.

---

This is the encoding performed by the example, it makes 25 dummy `Frames` for 1 second of video, and later, in the end, it loop through `avcodec_encode_video2()` looking for `got_output` for delayed frames:

```
/////  Prepare the Frame, CodecContext and some aditional logic.....

/* encode 1 second of video */
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
    pkt.size = 0;
    fflush(stdout);
    /* prepare a dummy image */
    /* Y */
    for (y = 0; y < c->height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < c->width; x++) {
            frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
        }
    }
    /* Cb and Cr */
    for (y = 0; y < c->height/2; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < c->width/2; x++) {
            frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
            frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
        }
    }
    frame->pts = i;
    /* encode the image */
    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (got_output) {
        printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
        fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }
}
/* get the delayed frames */
for (got_output = 1; got_output; i++) {
    fflush(stdout);
    ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, NULL, &got_output);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (got_output) {
        printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
        fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }
}

/////  Closes the file and finishes.....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delay is fixed, so your encoder delay will never go above `delay` frames. Therefore, the memory consumption does not increase as recording length goes up, and thus there is no issue, leading to the correct answer 1: you flush only at the end of the encode.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ronald! I am finishing my code for testing, as soon as I test everything I will accept all your answers!